# Cannot set sort order of custom fields in profile

Tags: custom-fields, profile, joomla

I created a custom group and populated with custom fields. When I preview all fields in group, it is in the correct order.
[image: custom group profile]

When I use the custom group in a profile, the profile reverses the order.
[image: Profile group view]

I've tried changing weights to order, but I can't seem to make it work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

The weight of the custom fields only controls the order in which they appear on the back end.  The profile sets its own order.  You can set the order from **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Profiles**, then clicking the **Fields** link next to the profile you want to edit and using the "Order" buttons (see screenshot).

[image]